# Selenium VBA to extract DATA into Excel

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver

Sir 
I am getting problem to get Data into excel I have some selenium code to get data from URL max pagination number. in to excel.

[here is url](https://www.justdial.com/Rajkot/Software-Companies/page-60)

```
Public Sub URL_Max_Page()
Dim driver As New ChromeDriver
Dim URL As String

'open the page with the URL
    URL = "https://www.justdial.com/Rajkot/Software-Companies/page-60"

driver.Get [URL]

'get maximum page number in to excel

MX = driver.FindElementsById("paginationlastPageNum").Text

   ActiveSheet.Range("A7") = MX
   driver.Quit

End Sub
```

I am getting some error .. i don't know how to make my code working

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure but try this

```
Public Sub URL_Max_Page()
    Dim driver As New ChromeDriver, aScriptParts, mx, sURL As String, sResp As String, sScriptPart As String, i As Long
    sURL = "https://www.justdial.com/Rajkot/Software-Companies/page-60"
    With driver
        .Get [sURL]
        sResp = .PageSource
        aScriptParts = Split(sResp, "<script", , vbTextCompare)

        For i = LBound(aScriptParts) + 1 To UBound(aScriptParts)
            sScriptPart = Split(aScriptParts(i), "</script", , vbTextCompare)(0)
            If InStr(sScriptPart, "paginationPageNum") Then
                mx = Split(Split(sScriptPart, "paginationPageNum = ")(1), ";")(0)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
        Debug.Print mx
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @YasserKhalil Sir. its perfect as I want. thanks a lot

Comment: Sir Can you Help me more.. if I have multiple url list ... how I can loop this code to all urls .

Comment: It is better to post a new question and I will have a look and see if I can help.